# Existence of a linear continuous function

Tags: functional-analysis

I found the following problem:

> Let $(H,(\cdot,\cdot))$ be a Hilbert space and B a continuous Bilinear form on H. Then there is a $A\in L(H)$, with $L(H)$ being the linear, continuous functions $H\rightarrow H$, with $B(x,y)=(Ax,y) \forall x,y\in H$

I tried to use the Lax-Milgram theorem, which can be used on continuous 
koerziv sesquilinear forms. (A is a koerziv Sesequilinear form if there is an $a>0$ so that for all $u\in H$: $Re(A(u,u))\ge a||u||^2$).

> Let $a:H\times H\rightarrow\mathbb{K}$ be a continuous, koerziv sesquilinear form on a $\mathbb{K}$-Hilbert space. Then there is exactly one bijective function $A\in L(H)$, so that for all $u,v\in H$ is true: $a(v,u)=(v,Au)$

In the real numbers every sesquilinear form is a bilinear form which is koerziv. And since the dot product is symmetric, this would solve my problem for the real numbers. Do I have to specify it also for the complex numbers? I don't know how I could do this

Comment: I don't have time to turn this into an Answer.  You may be overthinking this.  Hint:  If $H = \{0\}$, this is trivial.  Otherwise, $H$ has an orthonormal basis $K$.  Once you evaluate $B$ on $K \times \{0\}$ and on $\{0\} \times K$, bilinearity of $B$ lets you directly assemble $A$.

Comment: Riesz' representation theorem should also let you construct $A$ quite easily.